# OData service on legacy database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

What is the best option to build an OData service on a legacy database?

All the tutorials are creating a database from scratch to match the entity framework model.

How does it work with an existing database that does not match the service model being exposed?

For example, I have these 2 db tables:

Science_Data { country_id varchar(3), year int, fig decimal }

Arts_Data { country_id varchar(3), year int, fig decimal }

and I want to expose it using this path /Category('Science')/Data and /Category('Arts')/Data (The ids are just for the example).

I was able to achieve some success by creating a service model that contains Category and Data entities and creating a controller:

```
public class CategoryController : ODataController
{
    [EnableQuery]
    [ODataRoute("/Category('{id}')/Data")]
    public IQueryable<Sector> Get([FromODataUri]string id)
    {
        if (id == "Science")
        { 
            return db.Science_Data.Select(i => new Data() { CountryId =    i.country_id, Year = year, Figure = fig });
        }
        else if(id == "Arts")
        {
            return db.Arts_Data.Select(i => new Data() { CountryId = i.country_id, Year = year, Figure = fig });
        }
    }
}
```

This works to a certain extent and supports query options and the filtering will happen at the database level.

But I'm having problems supporting $expand options so I'm wondering if my approach is correct to begin with.

Comment: Can you edit the database, add views/queries to re-order the data in a more useful way to you?

Comment: There is very limited control of the database because there are a lot of applications that are using the database and changing things can break them. I think this scenario is valid for most production systems that have been deployed for a long time.

Comment: Adding a query/view should not break existing ones.

Comment: Database views is one solution to bridge the gap between the database model and the service model however it's not always doable. For example say those 2 tables (Arts and Science) contains millions a of records each, putting them together in a view using a union will be a big performance hit.